# How can I get continous plot of ArcTan over all quadrants?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

Scope:

My calculation is an element in the optimization of a mechanism. The geometry is given by following equations. To get angles β and γ without using the inverse function `ArcTan` I asked for the tangents of those angles:

```
Solve[
  {r Cos[ϕ + δ] + m Cos[γ] + l Cos[β] + a == 0,
   r Sin[ϕ + δ] + m Sin[γ] + l Sin[β] - b == 0,
   x == Tan[β],
   y == Tan[γ]
  },
  {x, y}, {β, γ}]
```

All other variables are parameters.

The solution is a few pages long, so I do not paste it. It is given as sixth grade series. There are two solutions. The second corresponded to my case.

My **first** problem is that, even when I give the parameters values verified as working, the the funtions is "jumping" over the X-axis, as below:

```
tang[a_, b_, c_, d_, l_, m_, r_, ϕ_, δ_] := ...the answer for y...  

Plot[tang[0.282, 0.00382, 0.869, 0.0468, 0.149, 0.603, 0.303, 0.84, δ], {δ, -2, 2}]
```

Graph 1

[image: Tangens Graph 1]

My **second** problem is to get continuous ArcTan over another quadrants.

For a given tangent of β (solution x, same parameters):

Grapgh 2

[image: Tangens Grapgh 2]

`ArcTan` looks like this:

Graph 3

[image: ArcTangens Graph 3]

The angle should be a continuous function. This is coming of course from periodicity of tangent, but I need it to take into account all quadrants. I can't directly move it by `Piecewise` for values lesser than zero, because, dependings on parameters, the the real value can be in any quadrant. Solving equations directly for `ArcTan[x, y]` doesn't make any difference.

As I read the documentation, the "jumping" (Graph 1) may be caused by branch cutting the function by solver — but i have no idea how to prevent/control it.

I will be very grateful for any insight in my problems — I have already used up all my ideas.

Comment: Maybe use `Mod[atan, Pi, offset]` for an appropriate `offset`.  Or `Mod[atan, 2 Pi, offset]`. Note that over any closed interval of length 2 pi, `ArcTan` will be necessarily discontinuous.

Comment: @Michael E2 So maybe there is a way to obtain solution in other form? My goal is to get continous function of angles '\[Beta]' and '\[Gamma]'